# Is there a way to change the value of DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY env variable to 0?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I am deploying a simple flask app on docker swarm using the docker swarm documentation on docker hub. When I use the IP address of any of the docker machines it doesn't show the "Hello" message instead show a message.

I have tried to change the DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY env variable for windows but couldn't find or change anything. I also explicitly changed the variable in docker file but still nothing.

This is my docker file:

```
# from latest python as parent image
FROM python:latest

# set up the working directory 
WORKDIR /app

# copy the contents from current directory to /app
COPY . /app

# install the requirements from requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# set up the enviornment variable
ENV NAME World

# run the app.py when the container launches
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

This is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    # replace username/repo:tag with your name and repository ang docker hub
    image: ****/******
    deploy: 
      replicas: 5
      resources: 
        limits:
          cpus: "0.1"
          memory: 50M
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    ports:
      - "3000:5000"
    networks:
      - webnet
networks: 
  webnet:
```

expected result should be : Hello

actual result is : Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server

Comment: what is the error you get ?

Comment: @LinPy the error is the message "Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server" it should just print "Hello"

Comment: What are the exact commands that you use to build and tag the image and then to run the container?

Comment: @Mihai the commands mention in this given link: "https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part4/"